# Can I install the same copy of Windows 7 on different Harddrive on Same PC?

Tags: windows-7

I have Windows 7 installed on `Harddisk01` on my PC.  This copy holds my development environment.  I'd like to install Windows 7 on another harddrive on my PC, and let that copy handle things like gaming.

The reason is that when I'm developing, there are a lot of processess that start up; I'd like to keep from having to manually end those processes and have a configuration geared towards gaming.

If that isn't possible, is there a good tutorial on Windows Startup profiles that will help me configure Windows 7 in various profiles and stop/start services for each profile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short Answer, **No**. Slightly longer answer, you probably could, but you'll likely have licensing and activation issues to deal with.

An alternative method from the Startup profiles could be a simple batch script that cleans up processes before you start gaming. Create a new file on your desktop, rename it to "Gaming.bat", and put a line in for each unnecessary process:

```
TASKKILL /F /IM process.exe
```

The `/F` forcefully closes the process, so you can experiment with not using `/F` on some processes if you're afraid of lost data in those.

Answer (score 2):

Legally, no. Although it's on the same machine is still a separate instance of the OS. The license does not allow for concurrent installs unless you have a VLA (Volume Licensing Agreement).

Answer (score 1):

Failing the dual booting option, something like this may help... http://www.allscoop.com/dotnet-software/service-manager.php

I used a similar windows service manager application years ago and it worked well.  No recent experience though.